# Is the callstack a language-safe data structure? Quasar + Fortran?

Tags: java, multithreading, jna, coroutine, quasar

We have a java application backed by a fortran binary that we're actively developing. I'm mostly on the java side, and I consider it my job to protect the people who work on the fortran from some of the nasty systems things that might otherwise bother them, things like concurrency and not pressing them to expose complex APIs.

One decision I made along these lines was to pass a JNA style callback from java into our fortran binaries. When this callback gets executed, our callstack would look something like this:

```
UIframework.click.java -- com.sun#1234
OurCode.UIHandlers.java -- our.code#2345
OurCode.doHeavyComputation.java -- our.code#4567
JNASurrogates.java -- com.sun.jna#456
JNASurrogates.proxy.f99 -- com.sun.proxies
HeavyComputation.f99 -- /code/algorithm.f99#1234
JNASurrogates.executeCallback.proxy.f99 -- com.sun.proxies
JNASurrogates.java -- com.sun.jna#1234
OurCode.computationComponents.java -- our.code#6789
//bottom of callstack
```

My question is one of threads: how would two thread accesses to the same in-memory fortran DLL be handled? My question is rooted in the exact details of how callstacks are handled in memory: in order for a fortran compiler to produce code that can be called from JNA without having one program-counter clobber the other, that compiler would have to have some kind of shared understanding with the JVM about where the callstack is to be stored. Does X86 provide us with some kind of separate program-counter container that `Pthreads`, `java.lang.Thread`, and other threading libraries all leverage, allowing for safe isolation of callstacks?

---

To make things really interesting I'm also debating using [Quasar](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/) -- For those unfamiliar, Quasar offers what it calls "fibers", which are "light-weight threads", implemented by stackful co-routines, meaning Quasar performs direct manipulations of stack-frames.

The problem is that, while I'm conceptually quite happy to expose the `OurCode.computationComponents` as a callback, some business requirements are dictating that I cant. Rather than ask our illustrious fortran programmers to convert their existing code to something with explicit entry and exit (return) points, I would much rather use a coroutine to leverage our existing code.

The idea would be that a co-routine would *yield* at `OurCode.computationComponents.java` yielding any arguments that were passed in to `computationComponents` by `HeavyComputation.f99` as a returnvalue to the caller of `doHeavyComputation`. The caller would then do the work that the computationCompoennts callback normally does, passing the result in from that with `resumeHeavyComputation`, which would yield back to `computationComponents` and ultimately back to `HeavyComputation.f99`

I can of course do all of this with Blocking Queues and multiple threads, but trying to limit myself to using one thread means that I get some exposure to Quasar, which is nice for a couple reasons.

Can Quasar handle and safely restore a stack as complex as the one we're using?

Answer (score 1):

The OS provides threads.  Other programming models (Java, Quasar, whatever) have to build on top of that if they're in user space.  Your Quasar "lightweight threads" will all still live within the context of your OS process and OS threads.  Since your OS threads can share memory, so can your "lightweight threads".  Callbacks to Java via JNA from different "lightweight threads" will all appear to be in the same Java-mapped thread (and therefore the same native thread).

Whatever runtime stacks Quasar shuffles around for its coroutines will be largely opaque to the Java side.